# Does serial close voting by tag matter?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

During my review of close votes I have noticed that there is a significant fraction of questions tagged [israel](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israel) ([example](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/close/19463) 1, [example 2](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/close/19464)).

All these questions seemed fine for me and for the community as well (highly voted, high quality answers) and the close process was eventually ended (Leave Open).

I am wondering if such a practice (assumed close votes by tag) is something worth taking into the account by moderators.

**Question:** Does serial close voting by tag matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you for calling attention to this. But I don't see a reason for mod intervention here yet, because the community handles this issue very well on its own.

It takes 5 people to close a question. In both examples, all people reviewed as "leave open". So unless we actually get a coordinated group of at least 5 people who conspire to close all questions about topics they don't like and coordinate their timing well enough to get them closed before the review queue gets to them, there is no reason to worry. And in that case we can act on a question-by-question basis. When you see a question which got closed for a reason you don't consider valid, post on meta so the community can discuss what to do with the question.

And if *that* gets annoying, *then* we can consider to swing the mod-hammer against people who abuse the close questions privilege.

Besides, I could conceive why one would want to close both of these two questions for a reason which has nothing to do with antizionism: They are both very speculative. I see little point in closing them *now*, because they are both over a year old and got good answers. But if they were new questions I could fully understand why someone would vote to close.

Answer (score 4):

Serial voting is when a specific user is being targeted, not when a specific tag is being targeted. Users can be harassed by serial voting. Tags can't be the victims of harassment, because they're not people.

I'd note that not only do both mention Israel, but they both mention Daesh, and that they're fairly similar to each other.